# Background image for dynamically created div not showing up on iPad

Tags: html, css, ipad, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a web page where on click of a button some divs are added to a table, for styling I have given background image url to div, its working on all browsers but going to iPad background image of newly created div is not showing up.

It seems that those images are not loading, Any Idea how to solve this issue?

here is my css:

```
    .emailReply div {
    background: url(/images/coach/icons/reply-email-icon.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: center;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Try to specify a background color to see if the div is actually loaded

Comment: yes div is loaded and click events also firing @passatgt